# Boots & runs perfectly stable all processes working on battery not on mains adaptor

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, battery

> Toshiba Satellite A300
>
> Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit
>
> Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T5670 @ 1.8GHz
>
> 4GB RAM

It must be possible to find out what is the difference in booting on a battery or on mains adapter?

It isn't a faulty AC adapter - have tried it on another Satellite and all OK - tried another adapter from other Satellite and still same problem - on AC will reboot within 6 seconds, then might boot up but soon freezes or shuts down - no regular behavior.  So what gives?

Is it some process/service which loads within 6/10 seconds of switch on - after Toshiba logo appears - know this because there is time before and at logo time to F8 to Safe Mode - in which it runs stable for hours.

Obviously battery mode is not identical to Safe Mode - all features work in battery mode as they did/do in AC mode - nothing missing unlike Safe Mode.

Any ideas how I can set about to find the difference and make use to enable stable AC mode?

Answer (score 0):

Toshiba's [eco Utility](https://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=4010128) keeps the battery charged to 80%, rather than to 100%, to lengthen the time before the battery needs to be replaced. Since your issue occurs only while charging, you might try uninstalling *eco*. Before doing so, though, go to the [Toshiba support site](https://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=2238728) and download the *eco* driver to reinstall it if it's *not* the cause of the issue.

- Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and type `programs`.
- Select *Add or remove programs*.
- Scroll down to *Toshiba eco Utility*, double-click and uninstall it.

[image: Toshiba eco Utility]

If that resolves the issue, you can try updating the utility, to see if that works better.

Another possibility is that *Microsoft* battery maintenance drivers have been corrupted. One way to check is to [uninstall the current ACPI battery drivers](https://www.pcworld.com/article/225265/battery_not_charging.html) and let Windows find and replace the correct ones, either from disk or the internet.

- Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and type `device`.
- Select *Device Manager*.
- Open the *Batteries* section.
- Select *Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery Properties*.
- On the *Drivers* tab select Uninstall Device*.
- Scan for hardware changes and the driver should be reinstalled.
- Reboot and check if the issue recurs.

[image: Removing battery drivers]